# Correct way to pass a column to an imputer using labels?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following working code:

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy='mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X_train[['Age']])
X_train['Age'] = imputer.transform(X_train[['Age']])
```

And this throws me the following warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

When I use the following line I still get the same warning; why is that?:

```
X_train['Age'] = imputer.transform(X_train[['Age']])
```

If I try to apply the same logic to everything:

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy='mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X_train.loc[:,'Age'])
X_train.loc[:,'Age'] = imputer.transform(X_train.loc[:, 'Age'])
```

I get the following message and the `imputer` does not work:

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
>   single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Please, could anyone explain me what should be the correct way to pass a column to an imputer using labels?

I do not understand clearly the difference between using `[['Age']]` and `.loc[:,'Age']`, it looks like they have the same data but in a different shape.

Answer (score 2):

According the last error that you received, when you select a dataframe column like `imputer = imputer.fit(X_train.loc[:, 'Age'])` you actually pass a **Serie** to **Imputer** which is one-dimensional.

```py
type(X_train['Age'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

However, method `fit()` expects you to pass a two-dimensional array to it. Instead, you can use column Age index in a way that returns Dataframe (i.e two-dimensional):

```py
type(X_train.iloc[:,2:3])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Doing this way, you will not receive dimension error. I tested this for your purpose and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following method

```
X.loc[:,'Age'] = imputer.fit_transform(X[['Age']])
```

Working example:

```
import pandas as  pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

X = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [12,13,'NaN', 23,31,12,43,32,42,]})
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
X.loc[:,'Age'] = imputer.fit_transform(X[['Age']])

#
    Age
0   12.0
1   13.0
2   26.0
3   23.0
4   31.0
5   12.0
6   43.0
7   32.0
8   42.0
```

`imputer` would expect a 2D  {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features) or a DataFrame. when you just use `X['Age']`, it will return a pd.Series object. Instead, when you use `X[['Age']]`, Dataframe would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use fit_transform method

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values=0, strategy="mean", axis=0)
X_train[['Age']] = imputer.fit_transform(X_train[['Age']])
```